# How to add custom block at the /checkout/cart/ page?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, cart, blocks, magento-1

I am working on a custom extension and I want to add additional block to the /checkout/cart/ page.

Take a look:
[image]

Here is my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
        <expressdelivery>
            <class>VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>vivasindustries_expressdelivery_resource</resourceModel>
        </expressdelivery>
        <vivasindustries_expressdelivery_resource>
        <class>VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <expressdelivery>
            <table>VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery</table>
            </expressdelivery>
        </entities>
        </vivasindustries_expressdelivery_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <expressdelivery_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                 <use>core_setup</use>
             </connection>
        </expressdelivery_setup>
        <expressdelivery_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </expressdelivery_read>
        <expressdelivery_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </expressdelivery_write>
    </resources>    
    <helpers>
        <expressdelivery>
            <class>VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery_Helper</class>
        </expressdelivery>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <expressdelivery>
             <class>VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery_Block</class>
        </expressdelivery>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <expressdeliveryadmin>
                                        <title>Vivas - All</title>
                                    </expressdeliveryadmin>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <expressdelivery>
                <file>expressdelivery.xml</file>
            </expressdelivery>
        </updates>
    </layout>   
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery before="Mage_Adminhtml">VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery_Adminhtml</VivasIndustries_ExpressDelivery>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0.0">
    <checkout_cart_index>
         <reference name="checkout.cart">
            <block type="core/template" name="expressdelivery_ccart" template="expressdelivery/cart.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
</layout>
```

Here is my phtml Block located in /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/expressdelivery/cart.phtml:

```
This is a test!
```

And this simple text does not appear, why ?

My /checkout/cart.phtml :

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     rwd_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Shopping cart template
 *
 * @var $this Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart
 */
?>
<?php $_priceDisplay = ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()) ? 'display-both-prices' : 'display-single-price'; ?>
<div class="cart <?php echo $_priceDisplay; ?>">
    <div class="page-title title-buttons">
        <h1><?php echo $this->__('Shopping Cart') ?></h1>
        <?php if(!$this->hasError()): ?>
        <ul class="checkout-types top">
        <?php foreach ($this->getMethods('top_methods') as $method): ?>
            <?php if ($methodHtml = $this->getMethodHtml($method)): ?>
            <li><?php echo $methodHtml; ?></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form_before') ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">
        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
        <table id="shopping-cart-table" class="cart-table data-table">
            <col width="1" />
            <col width="1" />
            <col width="1" />
            <col width="1" />
            <col width="1" />
            <col width="1" />
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
            <col width="1" />
            <col width="1" />
            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php $mergedCells = ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices() ? 2 : 1); ?>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Product') ?></span></th>

                    <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>">&nbsp;</th>

                    <th class="a-center cart-price-head" colspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>">
<!--                            <div class="cart-price-placeholder">-->
                            <span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></span>
<!--                            </div>-->
                    </th>

                    <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>" class="a-center">
                        <?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>

                        <?php /*if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllowInCart()) : ?>
                            <span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Move to Wishlist') ?></span>
                        <?php endif*/ ?>

                    </th>

                    <th class="a-center cart-total-head" colspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>">
<!--                            <div class="cart-total-placeholder">-->
                            <?php echo $this->__('Subtotal') ?>
<!--                            </div>-->
                    </th>

                    <th class="a-center" rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>">&nbsp;</th>

                </tr>
                <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="a-center cart-price-head"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?></th>
                    <th class="a-center cart-price-head"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?></th>
                    <th class="a-center cart-total-head"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?></th>
                    <th class="a-center cart-total-head"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?></th>
                </tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="50" class="a-right cart-footer-actions">

                        <!-- Make this button the first responder rather than empty cart -->
                        <button type="submit" style="visibility:hidden;" name="update_cart_action" value="update_qty" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Cart'); ?>" class="button2 btn-update"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Cart'); ?></span></span></button>

                        <button type="submit" name="update_cart_action" value="empty_cart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Empty Cart'); ?>" class="button2 btn-empty" id="empty_cart_button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Empty Cart'); ?></span></span></button>

                        <button type="submit" name="update_cart_action" value="update_qty" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Cart'); ?>" class="button2 btn-update"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Cart'); ?></span></span></button>

                        <!--<span class="or">-or-</span>-->

                        <?php if($this->getContinueShoppingUrl()): ?>
                            <a href="./../../" style="font-family:Verdana; display:block; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:none;"><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
                        <input type="hidden" id="update_cart_action_container" />
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        //<![CDATA[
                            Event.observe(window, 'load', function()
                            {
                                // Internet Explorer (lt 8) does not support value attribute in button elements
                                $emptyCartButton = $('empty_cart_button');
                                $cartActionContainer = $('update_cart_action_container');
                                if ($emptyCartButton && $cartActionContainer) {
                                    Event.observe($emptyCartButton, 'click', function()
                                    {
                                        $emptyCartButton.setAttribute('name', 'update_cart_action_temp');
                                        $cartActionContainer.setAttribute('name', 'update_cart_action');
                                        $cartActionContainer.setValue('empty_cart');
                                    });
                                }

                            });
                        //]]>
                        </script>
                        <![endif]-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('shopping-cart-table')</script>
    </form>

    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('shopping.cart.table.after'); ?>
    <div class="cart-forms">
        <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('checkout_cart_widget') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('checkout.cart.extra') ?>
    </div>
    <div class="cart-totals-wrapper">
        <div class="cart-totals">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals'); ?>
            <?php if(!$this->hasError()): ?>
            <ul class="checkout-types bottom">
            <?php foreach ($this->getMethods('methods') as $method): ?>
                <?php if ($methodHtml = $this->getMethodHtml($method)): ?>
                <li class="method-<?php echo preg_replace("/[^_a-zA-Z0-9-]/", '-', $method); ?>"><?php echo $methodHtml; ?></li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('expressdelivery_ccart'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('crosssell') ?>
</div>
```

How can I add a custom block below that block?
Can anybody please help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: show  you update layout xml. You need write like `<checkout_cart_index><reference name='content'><block name='blabla' type='yourmoduel/block' etc...></reference></checkout_cart_index>`

Comment: Can you form a complete answer so i can mark it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to add the following to your `config.xml` under the `<config>` tag:

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <expressdelivery>
                <file>expressdelivery.xml</file>
            </expressdelivery>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Then you need to create your layout file `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/expressdelivery.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="0.1.0">
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <checkout_cart_index>
         <reference name="checkout.cart">
              <block type="core/template" name="extra_block" template="link/to/your/template" />
         </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>

</layout>
```

Then in your `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template/checkout/cart.phtml` you'll need to add the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_block'); ?>
```

Before this code:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('crosssell') ?>
```

Comment: if added `output='toHtml' ` in block when render to be automaticaly.

Comment: I have done all what you say but it is not working. Anything does not appear.

Comment: @TonyStark what did you write in your template ?

Comment: @TonyStark this answer correct, but you need determine reference block. You can enable show block hits in `admin->system->configuration->for develop` chose store view and enable `block hints` option. After refrash page and look in when block you whant past you block. Find this block in layouts file in layout/ directory `rwd` themes, get the name. And correct `reference name=''needed_block'` and write options `output='toHtml'` in you layout update file... p.s. sorry for my English.

Comment: @TonyStark I've updated my answer, a part of XML is missing in your config