# magento1.9 Add block in checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9

> Add a block below discount code form

[image: Add block]

Comment: follow below link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125118/how-to-add-custom-block-at-the-checkout-cart-page                                                               
manage the reference name accordingly.

Comment: How to get custom amount in front end magento1

Answer (score 0):

You can try the steps describe below to add a block in checkout cart page

**Step 1)**

Edit you Magento 1 Theme file checkout.xml.

I assume your current theme is "**rwd default**"
So you need to edit the **checkout.xml** file under 
***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout***

Insert <**block type="core/template" name="checkout.cart.donation" as="donation" template="checkout/cart/donation.phtml"/>** under parent block "**checkout.cart.coupon**" as below

```
...........
...........
    <checkout_cart_index translate="label">
        <label>Shopping Cart</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
                <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>checkout/cart.phtml</value></action>
                <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
                <action method="chooseTemplate"/>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>

                <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.empty.widget" as="checkout_cart_empty_widget" translate="label">
                    <label>Empty Shopping Cart Content Before</label>
                </block>

                <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.top_methods" as="top_methods" translate="label">
                    <label>Payment Methods Before Checkout Button</label>
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.top" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml" after="-" />
                </block>                

                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="checkout.cart.form.before" as="form_before" translate="label">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Items Before</label>
                </block>

                <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.methods" as="methods" translate="label">
                    <label>Payment Methods After Checkout Button</label>
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
                    <block type="checkout/multishipping_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.multishipping" template="checkout/multishipping/link.phtml"/>
                    <remove name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage" />                   
                </block>

                <block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.extra" translate="label">
                    <!-- Add Custom Donation Block-->
                    <block type="core/template" name="checkout.cart.donation" as="donation" template="checkout/cart/donation.phtml"/>
                    <label>Checkout Forms Extra</label>
                </block>                        
                <block type="checkout/cart_shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.widget" as="checkout_cart_widget" translate="label">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Items After</label>
                </block>
                <block type="checkout/cart_crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" as="crosssell" template="checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml"/>

                <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.cart.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/cart/totals.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" translate="label">
            <label>Additional Product Info</label>
        </block>
    </checkout_cart_index>
```

............
............

**Step 2)**

Create the phtml file **donation.phtml** under the active theme's checkout/cart.

I assume your current theme is "**rwd default**"
So you need to create the **donation.phtml** file under

***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/***

**File** : donation.phtml

```
<form id="donation-form" name="donation-form" action="#" method="post">
    <div class="donation">        
        <div class="donation-form">            
            <div class="field-wrapper">
                <input class="input-checknot" type="checkbox" id="is_donate" name="is_donate" value="" /> Donate
                <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add Donate')) ?>" 
                 class="button  btn-donate"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add Donate')) ?></span></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>

<style type="text/css">
#donation-form
{
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    ont-family: "Helvetica Neue", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #636363;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
</style>
```

Note: Please change the phtml file as per your needs

[image]

Comment: Without overwrite in checkout page how can i bring it in my module

Comment: Then how to get custom donation amount from user and add to total page

Comment: To taking the donation and display the donation amount you need to create a separate module with controller, Model, DB Setup. The answer was given to show the custom block only. Thank you.

Comment: How can i create , can you give any reference for this..

Comment: How to get form value from phtml and save it to total in checkout page

Comment: @PritamInfo24 I have small doubt, is my block type right : {{block type="core/template" template="top_selling_items_list/top_selling.php"}}  my top_selling.php available at app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/page/top_selling_items_list/top_selling

Comment: No. your Block type is not right. Block type is the php block class of the Module and template is is phtml file of the Module or Theme.
For example: <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="my.blockname"  template="Magento_Theme::html/mytemplate.phtml">